# frxBarCode.dcu not found - Delphi XE3 with FastReport 4

Tags: delphi-xe3, fastreport

I've migrated a Delphi 7 project to Delphi XE3.
Delphi XE3 has FastReport 4, but the frxBarCode.dcu file was not found.
I noticed that this file only exists in the C: \ Program Files (x86) \ FastReports \ LibD17x64 folder.
But I am compiling my project on Target Platform = 32 bits and not on 64 bits.
How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I reinstalled fastreport 5 and this time the unit frxBarCode.dcu was installed. I think there was a bug in the first installation.